# Preorder traversal of OBST from root matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am trying to do a pre-order traversal of a OBST and print it out in file format.  I am correctly computing the OBST's cost and root matrix.  I can also output the tree nodes in the correct format, but I am having trouble figuring out how to display a parent with no children.

What part of the root matrix denotes that a node has no children or only one child?  I understand how to traverse it, and to output the nodes correctly, just not ones with no children.

Ex:  The elements are {A, B, C, D} with probabilities {10, 20, 40, 30}.

I compute the cost matrix and root matrix, then use the root matrix to output a tree.  It should look like this:

```
C
 B
  A
   _
   _
  _
 D
  _
  _
```

Mine looks like this:

```
 C
  B
   A
    _
   _
  _
  D
   _
```

This is my pre-order function:

```
void PrintTree(int i, int j, int space)
{
if(i < j)
{
    outfile.write("", space++);
    outfile<<A[Rt[i][j]]<<endl;

     PrintTree(i, Rt[i][j], space);
     outfile.write("",space);  //This line
     outfile<<"-"<<endl;       //This line
     PrintTree(Rt[i][j] + 1, j, space);
}
}
```

I'm almost 100% sure the lines inbetween the recursive calls are either wrong or should not even be there.  Basically, how do I correctly format those dashes to be children that don't exist.

Comment: Optimal binary search tree sorry...

Comment: my bad, sorry but I don't think obst is a widely used acronym

Comment: All good, I solved my problem, now I just need to figure out why I'm outputting weird characters to file.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered my own question.

Should be:

```
void PrintTree(int i, int j, int space)
{
if(i < j)
{
    outfile.write("", space++);
    outfile<<A[Rt[i][j]]<<endl;
     PrintTree(i, Rt[i][j], space);
     PrintTree(Rt[i][j] + 1, j, space);
}
else
{
    outfile.write("",space);  //This line
     outfile<<"-"<<endl;      
}
}
```

This works for small trees...but now I'm getting weird characters.

Ì    ... i dunno where this is coming from as it doesn't happen on input less than 10.